# php imagejpeg()

Tags: php

I am trying to put a rotate img function on my site. I am using imagejpeg() but it returns a sloo full of gibberish. Can you explain why?

```
                if ($_GET["rotate"] == "clockwise")
                {

                    $degrees = 90;

                    // Content type
                    //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

                    // Load
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);

                    // Rotate
                    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

                    // Output

                    if (imagejpeg($rotate))
                    echo "Your image has been rotated clockwise";
                } 
                if ($_GET["rotate"] == "counterclockwise")
                {
                    $degrees = 270;

                    // Content type
                    //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

                    // Load
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);

                    // Rotate
                    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

                    // Output
                    if (imagejpeg($rotate))
                    echo "Your image has been rotated Counterclockwise";
                }
                ?>
```

It pastes this onto the page:

ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ÿÛC     $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC     2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀûÛ"ÿÄ   ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ     ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á (AND ON AND ON FOR A LONG WAY)

If I change it to clockwise the gibberish changes as well, so I think it's working somewhat, but it's not creating a jpg from it. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: add: header('content-type:image/jpeg') before output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That *is* the image. You're just not telling your browser that it is, your browser interprets the data as text. Set a header to tell your browser to interpret the data as image:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

The image data will have to be the only thing output on the page, no other HTML or text before or after it.

Comment: Thanks. Is that not the function to use then, if I want to permanently change the orientation of the image file?

Comment: It is. Just what you do with the result is wrong apparently. You maybe want to save the result back to a file.