# Load image base64 from url to src

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, base64

This is a continuation of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119732/captcha-works-fine-in-localhost-but-not-in-my-hosting).

So i need load img (base64) from URL: http://test-pb.linuxpl.info/rejestracja-darmowa?task=show_captcha_image

To [my hmtl site](http://test-pb.linuxpl.info/rejestracja-darmowa)

```
<img align="middle" id="captcha_image" title="Please enter the code you see in the image into Security code textbox" src="http://test-pb.linuxpl.info/rejestracja-darmowa?task=show_captcha_image">
```

Comment: This question is not clear. The question you linked to seems to address your problem. What further information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

instead of finding a workaround im addressing the orginal issue, the image data from your server is transferred as plain text add the following before sending the image data

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

Comment: Works but captcha code is wrong, see now i live: http://test-pb.linuxpl.info/rejestracja-darmowa#

Comment: captcha code id wont be the same as on page load since it is loaded in different session(iframe) it will be different. will provide you a work around

Comment: any other solution? meybe load image in js, ajax ?